# Can I Integrate rbsWorldPay payment gateway with nSoftware component with ASP.NET if yes then please provide sample code?

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, payment

We currently use nSoftware payment integrator 4.0 service for processing credit card through our application.

I would like to process payments through  "RBS WorldPay". I already set gateway to gwWorldPay till then I dont communicate to this gateway.

I already set Merchant login, merchant password, Installation ID but its not working Its give me response data like this :-

```
N,-1,PMII.badPayMethodAndAcqAmount,,1,.
```

Can you please provide us sample code or user guide for this problem ?

I hope you help me out on this problem.

Thank you

Comment: `Here I have attached screen shots`, where?

Comment: @Tushar: Your question title is "Can...?" but what you want is sample code and user guide. Considering this is integration with a proprietary 3rd party solution provider, we might need the user guide to answer your question.

Comment: I believe the correct answer to this question would be "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

Version 5.0 of nSoftware [lists RBS WorldPay as one of the new credit card gateways they support](http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/epayment/features.aspx) - given that you're already using version 4.0 of that system to do the heavy lifting for you, that would seem the simplest (if more expensive) solution.

If that's not possible, then what you'd need to implement depends on what sort of payments you'd be taking, but [RBS WorldPay's page of example integrations](http://www.worldpay.com/support/bg/index.php?page=development&sub=integration&subsub=examples) and [guide to submitting transactions by HTML redirect](http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/htmlredirect/rhtml.html) should hopefully start you on your way.